# Is it possible to have below layout without using position absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want to avoid any change in HTML as that may cause regression on other layouts and designs. As we are using same template across all design and layouts.

Need to achieve below layout without using position absolute for `.content2`. And `content2` and `content3` should have equal height.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: red;
}

.content2 {
  background: green;
}

.content3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.newLayout {
  position: relative;
}

.newLayout .content2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 92px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.newLayout .content3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper newLayout">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentia</div>
  <div class="content2">Content Two</div>
  <div class="content3">Content Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flexbox` you'd need to have *nested flexboxes* to have this layout. A 2D layout like this would be an *ideal* case for [`CSS grids`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "one three";    
}

.content {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
}

.content2 {
  grid-area: two;
  background: green;
}

.content3 {
  grid-area: three;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentia</div>
  <div class="content2">Content Two</div>
  <div class="content3">Content Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks ... Is it possible to do using display: flex?

Comment: you'd need to have *nested* flexboxes then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmceLf0k/)

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}
.leftBox{
background:red
}
.leftBox, .rightBox{display:flex;flex-flow:column;}
.contentTwo, .contentThree{height:50%}
.contentTwo{background:green;}
.contentThree{background:yellow;}
```

Comment: You have changed markup. I want to avoid that. display: grid is better option.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 92px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 1fr;
}

.content {
  grid-area: 1/1/3/2;
  background: red;
}

.content2 {
  grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
  background: green;
}

.content3 {
  grid-area: 2/2/3/3;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentia</div>
  <div class="content2">Content Two</div>
  <div class="content3">Content Three</div>
</div>
```